# Python - Adding characters to string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a password generator. I've tried using a for loop to generate each digit. I then appended each digit to a list. However, I want the output to be something along the lines of:

```
54324
```

rather than:

```
[5, 4, 3, 2, 4]
```

The following is my code:

```
    code = ''
    chars = 5
    for i in range(chars):
        digit = str(randint(0,9))
        digit += code
```

What happens in this scenario is that my output is just blank. I am somewhat new to python, so I may be missing something obvious, but I would appreciate if you could explain what I've done wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: `"".join(map(str,[5, 4, 3, 2, 4]))` should do it

Comment: but your code does nothing useful since `digit` is overwritten at each call of the loop. and `code` is empty.

Comment: Reverse your last statement: `code += digit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Corrected version of your code

```
from random import randint
code = ''
chars = 5
for i in range(chars):
  digit = str(randint(0,9))
  code += digit
print(code)
```

by the way, you can just use

```
code = randint(0,99999)
print(code)
```

to generate your password, just saying

Answer (score 1):

Your code is overwriting `digit` each time. You generate a random integer between 0 and 9, then turn it into a string. Then you add a `code` to this `digit` string. Then the next iteration of the for loop, you generate a new value for `digit`. So you shouldn't be getting a blank value- you should be getting a one-digit value for `digit`, a string representation of an integer between 0 - 9.

Your values should be assigned and added onto `code`, not `digit`.

```
code = ''
chars = 5
for i in range(chars):
    digit = str(randint(0, 9))
    code += digit

print(code)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beside the obvious error in your code, fixing it will give you an underperformant code:

- ugly `for` loop
- 5 calls to the random generator
- 5 conversions from int to string
- string concatenation

If you want to generate a password made of exactly 5 numbers, since there's no requirement of uniqueness of the digits (as seen in another similar question where this technique could not apply), you could generate a number < 100000 and format it with leading zeros using a nested `format`:

```
import random

nb_digits = 5

for _ in range(10):
    print("{:0{}}".format(random.randrange(0,10**nb_digits),nb_digits))
```

example of output:

```
58260
12986
69233
42343
02760
58934
06396
22262
07662
00182
```

Answer (score 0):

At each loop, you are erasing the previous value contained by the variable digit, and you variable code is not useful here because it is empty.

You could just do:

```
chars = 5
for i in range(chars):
    digit += str(randint(0,9))
```

Answer (score 0):

you were trying to print **digit** which is single digit random number, you have to append it to some other string to store

```
from random import randint
code = ''
chars = 5
for i in range(chars):
    digit = str(randint(0,9))
    code = code  +digit
print(code)
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Since you are appending to `code` it should go like:

```
code +=digit
```